# Copy or New instance of an interface

Tags: go

I have a function that takes an interface and returns an interface. It would like to initialize the result to a copy of the source, then make some changes, and return the result. For example:

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/xoITFiXHPY)

```
type Something interface {
    CopySomething() Something  // I'd like to get rid of this
    SetX(x int)
}

type RealThing struct {
    x int
}

func (t *RealThing) SetX(x int) {
    t.x = x
}

func (t *RealThing) CopySomething() Something {
    newT := *t
    return &newT
}

func Updated(original Something, newX int) Something {
    newThing := original.CopySomething()  // I'd like to make the copy without .CopySomething()
    newThing.SetX(newX)
    return newThing
}

func main() {
    a := &RealThing{x: 1}
    b := Updated(a, 5)
    fmt.Printf("a = %v\n", a)
    fmt.Printf("b = %v\n", b)
}
```

This works, but the `CopySomething()` method seems unnecessary (and I'd need another identical method for every interface that needs to copy things). Is there a better way to make a copy of `original` inside of `Updated()` without an extra method? Is there some more idiomatic way to achieve this?

In the specific case I'm working on, I could get away with just instantiating a new instance of the same type as `original` (I don't really need the copy). Is the problem any simpler that way?

---

Based on Evan's comment, I thought I'd give some of the other reflect-based things I've already tried:

```
newThing := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(original))
```

==>
Compile error: type reflect.Value has no field or method SetX

```
newThing := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(original)).Interface().(Something)
```

===>
Runtime error: interface conversion: **main.RealThing is not main.Something

```
newThing := reflect.Indirect(reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(original))).Interface().(Something)
```

===>
Runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

At this point, I felt my reflect was becoming silly and stopped just whacking at it.

Comment: is there a way to refactor this to not use pointers? Then you would be getting a shallow copy within the interface automatically.

Comment: I don't understand. How would you not use pointers, but still implement SetX?

Comment: ah, never mind. I was in a rush and wasn't thinking it through. You'd have to make X a pointer inside the struct, and is probably going to make it more convoluted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you just need to instantiate a new instance you can use reflection to get the type of the object stored in the interface and instantiate a copy that way. Something like `reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(x))` though you may have to play with `reflect.Indirect()` in order to allocate a new value and not a new pointer.

It's all documented here: http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/

And a runnable version: http://play.golang.org/p/z8VPzDKrSk

Comment: I went deep down that road without success. The "play with reflect.Indirect()" part was one of many variations :D Do you know how to actually get there? (This particular version gives type "reflect.Value has no field or method SetX")

Comment: This works but, in my opinion, the `Copy()` method on the interface makes more sense. Your concrete implementation might have more than the x int which you wouldn't know about only through the interface.

Comment: @RobNapier, if you decide to go down the reflection route, take a look at this: http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/rog-go/exp/deepcopy

Comment: @VitorDeMario, why does it matter if you know about the other fields? Evan's solution just gives back a Zero from New(). Though I'm finding that maybe I did need to make a copy…

Comment: @RobNapier I suppose you want a full copy of the `original` value. Suppose there's an `ExtraThing` implementation of the interface which includes more fields. A `y float64` perhaps. If `y` was set to anything other than 0.0, you'll lose that information. This may be ok in your use case.

Comment: Evan's solution set's *everything* to Zero. It's not making a copy. (He's working off of my comment near the end that I could get away without making a real copy.)

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood what he did (as well as what you wanted). In the end of the day, you don't need a copy at all, just a new object of the same concrete type as `original`? If that's the case, Evan's example is indeed enough.

Comment: Yeah; but it's turned out I probably do need a copy. Right now I'm using the `Copy()` method. It's just "cc := c; return &cc" (which I hate copying to every implementation...) But the reflection solution is a bit complex, and I'm avoiding adding a third-party dependency for one line of code.

Comment: What's weird is that you can make copies of slices with the built-in copy, but you can't copy just one item.

Comment: I think we should take this to chat.

Answer (score 2):

> newThing := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(original))
>
> > ==> Compile error: type reflect.Value has no field or method SetX

If original is an pointer is need get element:

```
elem := reflect.TypeOf(original).Elem()    
newThing := reflect.New(elem)
```

> newThing :=
>   reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(original)).Interface().(Something)
>
> > ===> Runtime error: interface conversion: **main.RealThing is not main.Something

Fixing and continuing...
Knowing that newThing is **pointer** for an new RealThing element, then get this pointer by .Interface(), but on interface{}.

```
elem := reflect.TypeOf(original).Elem()    
newThingValue := reflect.New(elem)
newThingInterf := newThingValue.Interface()
```

For get pointer direct to RealThing is need do assertion, then

```
newThing := newThingInterface.(*RealThing)
```

So you can update newThing normally

```
newThing.SetX(newX)//update new instance
```

See working in https://play.golang.org/p/N-pwH5J_el